# How to use Javascript to get current file name and use as a variable in Pug/HTML template?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I would like to pass the file name to the  tag in an html document. I would therefor like to grab it and put it in a variable. I am using Pug, so can use javascript before compiling to html.
This is obviously, obviously not correct code, but is the idea of what I need:
let **title tag** === **filename**.pug

I have tried this and it works in the browser, but it works off the url and I would like to do it off the OSX file path.
`var filename = (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)).replace('.html','');`
`document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = filename;`

Comment: Welcome to SO - Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your minimum efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something by showing some code or examples ? Please do your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a minimal example of your work. Read here how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can write [code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) in your `PUG` template

Comment: Read the file with the `fs` module? That's what it's here for (`fs.readFile()...`)